# How to save a pdf response to django model?

Tags: python, django

I have a function that calls for an external url to get a pdf format of specific car, so far this is the gist of what I tried:

```
def cars(id):

    headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Authorization': token
        }
    
    url = CAR_URL + f'/cars/{id}'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    return File(BytesIO(response.content))
    


def save_car_data(id)
    ...
    Car.objects.get_or_create(
        owner = 'Test Owner' # this gets saved
        pdf = cars(id) # this doesnt get saved
    )
```

Model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    created_dttm = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to="cars/", blank=True, null=True)
```

but when I check the django admin it seems there is no file generated and just a button that uploads a file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you are saving your file. Can you try:

```
def cars_view(id):

    headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Authorization': token
        }
    
    url = CAR_URL + f'/cars/{id}'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    file = File(BytesIO(response.content))
    Cars.objects.create(pdf=file)
    return file
```

Comment: I don't want to save it in the same function I'm getting the data. I want to save in another function because I have other business logic to do before saving.

Comment: How does the data go from the function where you get the data to the function you want to save it in? Either way, you need to create a new Cars object or add it to an existing model and save it.